# provision users (with passwords)

Tags: jhipster

I want to provision/import a huge number of users, and generate them passwords, that I communicate to them via mobile phone/whatsapp in JHipster.

I've tried using `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder` for this, but when I test this, I can call my service like this, I get 401 all the time, even though that worked before...

Is there a better way to import users?  I only have an Excel/google docs sheet from where to import.  This is my first time using JHipster, I've only used spring-boot for several years up to now, and am thinking that I might have to move "back", but am reluctant...

Comment: JHipster uses Spring Boot, there's no difference for your requirement. If you know how to do it in Spring Boot, I can't see why you would not be able to do it the same way in a JHipster app. Your question lacks many details about what you tried, what is failing. Also, I'm not sure why you want to do the import from your app, if it's a one shot import using a spreadsheet, have you considered writing a simpler external app that would connect to your database?

Comment: Ensure that PasswordEncoder is encoding correctly, there might be some salt or algorithm which is used while saving application users.

Comment: I figured out my problem - it was something else entirely, i switched from postgresql to mysql back again (due to restrictions on the server), left the mysql jdbc driver configured, but conected to postgresl. This led to a login exception, that was swallowed by spring ("could not commit"). Well... everything else worked after I figured that out. Thanks anyways!